# Como criar evento de tag?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando um formulário e gostaria de adicionar tags a cada vez que um nome for selecionado com um autocomplete.

<kbd>[image: Adicionando tags]</kbd>

Isso seria o equivalente à adicionar tags a uma pergunta do SO. 
Gostaria de ter uma base sobre como começar a pesquisar sobre isso, pois apenas consegui simular com html e Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o componente Select2 para fazer isso. [Clique aqui para abrir o link.](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Exemplo:

```js
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Depois você consegue customizar o `template` colocando abaixo os que são selecionados como você está na imagem que você colocou como exemplo.

Exemplo modificando o template do componente:

```js
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="vendor/images/flags/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};

$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

Espero que tenha lhe ajudado.

Comment: Em outro tópico eu havia visto algo parecido, vou tentar e posto o resultado. Obrigado.